# Remove custom formatting from a sitcky (OSX Stickies)

Tags: macos, stickies

When pasting text into a sticky, the original font/color/style of the source text is preserved.  This can be really annoying over time.  Other applications have a clear formatting shortcut key (Google uses cmd-\, openoffice cmd-m).  What I'm looking for is:

- shortcut key to remove formatting / revert to default
- some sort of CLI prefs command that would force stickies to only use the default font
- paste/copy as plain text clipboard control?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just remember to press `Cmd-Opt-Shift-V` (*Paste and Match Style*) when pasting and you won't need to reset it all the time.

---

If you still want to reset:

1. `Cmd-N` to make a new temporary Sticky with default formatting,
2. `Cmd-Opt-C` to copy formatting,
3. `Cmd-W` to close Sticky
4. `Cmd-A` to select all
5. `Cmd-Opt-V` to apply (default) formatting (i.e. clear).

Alternatively press the following sequence to copy all content of a Sticky into a new one with default style:

1. `Cmd-A`,
2. `Cmd-C`,
3. `Cmd-N`,
4. `Cmd-Opt-Shift-V`

Using AppleScript and Automator you could create a Service that automates these keystroke sequences.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that shortcut key but that works - thanks!  Could they have made the modifier keys any more difficult to trigger?  Need a coke bottle in there  ;)

Comment: This is horrible. Apple should make a shortcut to clear formatting. Disappointing.

Comment: @BenWilde, agreed, this is really poor UX

Comment: This is not the feasible solution any more. Please see this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1035775/264002

Comment: @OmarTariq Still works for me in 10.14.6. But perhaps the default shortcut for _Paste and Match Style_ changed?

Answer (score 15):

Its not a full solution to what you asked (5 years ago), but with custom keyboard shortcuts, its possible to easily remap Cmd-V.

On El Capitan:

Go to: System Preferences, Keyboard, Shortcuts, App Shortcuts.

Plus sign to add a new shortcut.

Change the Application to 'Stickies'.

Menu Title: 'Paste and Match Style'

Keyboard Shortcut: [Press Cmd-V]

This is very similar to the accepted answer, but less keystrokes on a day to day basis.

Comment: definitely think this answer works better than the accepted one. thanks

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Notes app screws up formatting. and then pasting to match formatting is not a good option.
I found there is a "Remove Style" button in the format menu under font. And using the systems preferences, you can set a keyboard shortcut for this menu title as described in the other comment.
Now I can easily remove bad text style formatting that screws up my notes. I hope this might help you guys too.

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Also it can be done with the [Get Plain Text](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/get-plain-text/id508368068?mt=12) app. It is free.